# SIGSEGV in C error

Tags: c, algorithm, gcc, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

[image]I always get an SIGSEGV error whenever i am dynamically initializing arrays in C. Please tell me what am I doing wrong all the time?

The code works fine on TurboC but it gives SIGSEGV on an online judge which uses GCC.

[Programming Problem](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO14001)

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    long n,h,i,crane=0,box=0,temp=0;
    long *comm;
    scanf("%ld %ld",&n,&h);
    long *a = (long*)malloc(n*sizeof(long));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
    scanf("%ld",&comm[0]);
    i=0;
    while(comm[i]!=0)
    {
       i++;
       scanf("%ld",&comm[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;comm[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        if(comm[i]==3)
            box=1;
        if(comm[i]==4 && box==1)
        {
            a[crane]=(a[crane]+1);
            temp=0;
        }
        if(box==1 && (comm[i]==1 || comm[i]==2) && temp==0)
        {
             a[crane]=(a[crane]-1);
             temp=1;
        }
        if(crane!=0 && comm[i]==1)
            crane--;
        if(comm[i]==2)
            crane++;
        if(comm[i]==0)
            break;
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
       printf("%ld ",a[i]);
   free(a);
   free(comm);
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: Remember that execution of your program goes from the top to the bottom. Consider then your use of the variable `n` before you initialize it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh sorry, i got it. Lemme compile it again.

Comment: Yes it is, what do you think happens in your call to `malloc` when the value of `n` is *indeterminate* (and seemingly random)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude look i edited the code, compiled it again. Stil it gives the same error.

Comment: Then it's time to bring out the debugger. A segmentation fault is usually a sign of *undefined behavior* and you need to step through your code, line by line, in a debugger to find out when and where it happens.

Comment: All of the usages of `comm` gives undefined behaviour, since `comm` is an unintialised pointer.   If it worked under Turbo C, that's just happenstance.   It was undefined behaviour then too - one of the potential outcomes of undefined behaviour is "seeming to work as intended anyway".

Comment: So.. initialzing and maintaining the size of comm* is not trivial, so you decided to just not allocate it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, *nowhere* in that code are you actually allocating memory for `comm` to point to. You apparently know this is required since you've done something similar for `a` and you free both `a` *and* `comm` at the end.

You need to `malloc` the memory for `comm` to point to, before using it. For example, if you wanted that to depend on the second value input (`h`, probable since it's not used anywhere else), you would need to add in:

```
comm = malloc(h*sizeof(long));
```

after the first `scanf`, noting that I *don't* cast the return value - you shouldn't do that in C.

If you *don't* know how big `comm` should be before using it, the usual way to handle that is to allocate a certain number of elements (the capacity) and keep track of how many you've used (the size). Each time when your size is about to exceed your capacity, use `realloc` to get more space.

The following (C-like) pseudo-code shows how to do this, starting with an empty array and expanding it by thirty elements each time more space is needed:

```
comm = NULL
capacity = 0
size = 0
for each value in input():
    if size == capacity:
        capacity += 30
        comm = realloc (comm, capacity), exit if error
    comm[size++] = value
```

Note that, on loop exit, `size` is the indicator of how many elements are in the array, despite the fact there may be more capacity.

---

And, as an aside, you should *always* assume that calls subject to failure (such as `scanf` and `malloc`) *will* fail at some point. In other words, *check* the return values.

Comment: I have to keep increasing the size until the input is 0, can't declare so many pointers to call realloc again and again.